# What causes error "Procedure unknown"

Tags: sql, firebird

So at my company we use a billing system which connects to a Firebird database that we have no back-end access to.  I am quite new at this company so my familiarity with the Firebird database is not too great.  We keep getting this error :

> ```
> ERROR: Database Engine Error
> Sender Class: TGLPreviewBtn
> Exception Class: EIBODBError.
> IBO ErrorERRCODE=335544569 SQLCODE=-204
> Error Message:
> ISC ERROR CODE:335544569
>
> ISC ERROR MESSAGE:
> Dynamic SQL Error
> SQL error code = -204
> Procedure unknown
> GET_SUB_CONTACTLIST
> At line 3, column 60
> ```

This has been a recurring thing since I've been hired (I've been here for about 45 days), and we've reported this error to the company which hosts the billing system that we use to access the database.  The company keeps saying that it's a network issue on our end, however I cannot see any indication of a connection drop on our end.

I have to reiterate that we have no back-end access to this database so I have no way of going to see what GET_SUB_CONTACTLIST even refers to.

Any help will be appreciated, I am just out of college and this is my first job in a position like this so I will use this as a great learning experience.

Comment: if you had more access to the server or at least to the application, then you maybe could use impostor client library or Trace API to log all and every SQL request. This would slow down the system considerably. But if you would be able to get the specific query making call to this procedure and then connect to the database directly and check if the procedure exists - it would be more material evidence.  The company talks BS, but they can drum their chest and claim "we are professionals"

Comment: Additionally, in firebird.log text file on the server there should be all the events of "connection loss" logged. in Windows those look as WinSock errors 10053 and 10054 AFAIR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be a network error on your end. The error literally means that Firebird was asked to execute a stored procedure called `GET_SUB_CONTACTLIST`, and that stored procedure does not exist at that time.

So either someone (or something) is creating and dropping stored procedures on the fly, or part of the application is calling a stored procedure that simply does not exist.

As an aside: error 335544569 (aka `isc_dsql_error`) covers a broad range of error conditions with 'dynamic' SQL (in other words: most SQL related errors...), unfortunately a lot of client libraries do not communicate the more specific error code 335544581 (or `isc_dsql_procedure_err`).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Like I said I've had to experience with Firebird before so I was a bit confused at the answers from the company whose billing system we use.  Considering we don't have access to the database's back-end I can assume that there must be a problem between our billing application and their hosted database.

Comment: `creating and dropping stored procedures on the fly` and if they created race conditions, then there really may be effects form everywhere including network speed. So they may genuinely think network conditions being the cause the error, rather than merely exposing it.

Comment: @Arioch'The Good point, that might be a possible failure mode.

Comment: that said, today with EXECUTE BLOCK one only would need it, if SP has to calls itself recursively. Like when creating nested sets trees. I wish there was "Common procedure expression", something like "Common table expressions" but for the PSQL blocks

Comment: @Arioch'The Firebird 3 has [sub-routines](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rnfb30-psql-subroutines.html).